# alternative foreign key syntax

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, syntax

In MySQL you can assign a primary key constraint to a column using two different syntaxes:

after the column is defined, separated by coma, optionally in a new line

```
id int auto_increment,
primary key(id)
```

and beside the column like all other constraints and features like `not null` etc

```
id int auto_increment primary key
```

So what I am asking is there a way do something like that with the foreign key syntax? I mean the only way I know to assigning a foreign key is to do it on a separate line after the column definition and coma, like so:

```
column_name int,
foreign key (column_name) references table_name(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an alternative syntax. It's in the MySQL docs. It would be:

```
column_name int references table_name(id),
```

But it is only parsed (and **ignored**) in MySQL. So, you can't use it.